# How do we compute the CM discriminants without factoring?

Tags: elliptic-curves

In ECC, there is a parameter known as CM discriminants. Suppose that the trace of the curve is $t$ in $Z_p$. The amount of $s^2$ is the largest square dividing $t^2-4p$ then $\frac{t^2-4p}{s^2}$ is a square-free negative integer. The CM discriminant is $\frac{t^2-4p}{s^2}$ if $\frac{t^2-4p}{s^2} \mod 4 = 1$, otherwise as $4(\frac{t^2-4p}{s^2})$. How do we compute this parameter without factoring? Are there any algorithm for this? Can anybody write the program in Sage for computing D?

Answer (score 1):

We want to find $D=-n/s^2$ for $s^2$ the largest square dividing known $n=4p-t^2>0$ (where $t$ is the trace and $n$ is the order of an Elliptic Curve with an equation in $\mathbb F_p$), for the same reason [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/disc.html) does: ascertain $-D\ge B$ for some bound $B$ (SafeCurves has $2^{-100}=B$ ). **I had never attempted or researched that. This answer is a tentative wild guess**.

There is no known method with heuristic time polynomial in the size of $n$ that pulls the square factors of $n$ with certainty (or even high confidence AFAIK), as desired; and I have no idea for one working for the kind of $n$ considered.

The best I have to propose is *trying* to factor $n$ using methods used for general integers, in particular [Lenstra's ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization), different than those ([PPMPQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Multiple_polynomials) or [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)) that would be used for an RSA moduli of the size considered (in the order of $p$ at worse); and perform an early abort in the relatively rare case the full factorization is hard to obtain.

---

The (revised) method I propose goes:

1. Pull as many factors of $n$ as possible using trial division by small primes and optionally a little [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm).
2. At this point we have expressed $n$ as $n=u\prod{p_i}^{k_i}$ with distinct $p_i$, and each $k_i\ge1$. Improve that (e.g. by trial division of $u$ by each $p_i$) so that no $p_i$ divides $u$.
3. If $u$ is prime or $1$, then $D=-u\prod{p_i}^{k_i\bmod 2}$, we can test $-D\ge B$, stop.
4. If $u$ is a square (which is easily tested), then $D=-\prod p_i^{k_i\bmod 2}$, we can test $-D\ge B$, stop.
5. [optional] Try to pull out more factors of $u$ using a limited amount of [Pollard's p-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm), and [Williams's p+1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams%27s_p_%2B_1_algorithm) (as e.g. in [GMP-ECM](http://ecm.gforge.inria.fr/)); and if that succeeds improve the factorization and continue at (2.)
6. At this point, we know one of the following two things holds:

   - $u$ is the product of two distinct primes, none of which is one of our $p_i$;
   - $u$ is the product of three or more prime factors (that is, if $u=\prod{p_j}^{k_j}$ with $p_j$ prime then $\sum k_j\ge3$ ), therefore $u$ is divisible by a prime at most $\sqrt[3]u$.

   Now we use [Lenstra's ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) as e.g. in [GMP-ECM](http://ecm.gforge.inria.fr/) with hope to find a factor less than $\sqrt[3]u$, or less than the bound $B$. If that succeeds improve the factorization and continue at (2.)
7. If step (6.) did not uncover a factor, we have options:

   - Abandon our effort for this curve and try a new one with hope the check is easier;
   - Factor $u$ with [PPMPQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Multiple_polynomials) or [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve);
   - Output $D=-u\prod{p_i}^{k_i\bmod 2}$ which has only a low probability to be incorrect, bounded by the computable probability that the amount of Lenstra's ECM we did could not pull out a factor less than $\sqrt[3]u$
   - Affirm $-D\ge B$ which has only a low probability to be incorrect, bounded by the computable probability that the amount of Lenstra's ECM we did could not pull out a factor less than $B$

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. But this is not enough for me. I want to compute CM without using factoring algorithms like Pollard-rho,...  Which is probably very slow for 512-bit numbers.

Comment: @mehdi mahdavi oliaiy: Pollard's rho is too slow (I only propose it for small factors, and just added it's optional; it's a speedup for small factors, just like p-1 and p+1 are optional speedup for a sizable proportion of medium factors). What I propose revolves around Lenstra's ECM for the bulk of the work. That's going to be fast enough for many practical curves. GMP-ECM is easy to compile, or otherwise get running (`sudo apt install gmp-ecm` in ubuntu or mint).